# what's optimal way to coding in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm a newer in flutter code , It's the widgets tree is stranger for me , now I want to coding as a optimal way like separate a logic and widgets so I make this way but i don't Know its right and a common or there is a best

I have create folder `screens/[has all screens]`
nested Created for each screen folder like this `screens/upload/[has all files belong to this screen]`
inside I create 3 files 
`screens/upload/upload_screen.dart`
`screens/upload/upload_widgets.dart`
`screens/upload/upload_logic.dart`

upload screen

```
    class UploadScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UploadScreenState createState() => _UploadScreenState();
}

class _UploadScreenState extends State<UploadScreen> {
UploadWidgets uploadWidgets;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

     uploadWidgets = UploadWidgets(context);

    return ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
      value: UploadLogic(context),
      child: Consumer<UploadLogic>(
        builder: (context, logic, _){
          print(logic.chosenFile);
        return Scaffold(
          body:  logic.chosenFile == null ? uploadWidgets.buildInitContent() : Text('hello')
        );
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

upload logic

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class UploadLogic with ChangeNotifier {
  BuildContext context;
  File chosenFile;
  UploadLogic(this.context);

  Future<void> pickupImageFromCameraApp() async {
    final File imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      imageQuality: 95,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );

    chosenFile = imageFile;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

upload widgets

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import './upload_logic.dart';

class UploadWidgets {
  BuildContext context;
  UploadLogic uploadLogic;
  UploadWidgets(this.context) {
    uploadLogic = UploadLogic(context);
  }

  void showChoodeBottomModal() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(10), topRight: Radius.circular(10))),
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: 200,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('From Cameara'),
                  subtitle: Text('Take your photo from your camer app'),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.camera),
                  onTap: ()=>uploadLogic.pickupImageFromCameraApp(),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('From Gallary'),
                  subtitle: Text('choose your image from your gallary app'),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
                  onTap: () {},
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('From Cameara'),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.exit_to_app),
                  onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        });
  }

  Widget buildInitContent() {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
      width: double.infinity,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/images/upload.svg',
            height: 300,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Text(
            'Upload A new image',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          RaisedButton.icon(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.file_upload,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            label: Text(
              'Choose a file',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () => showChoodeBottomModal(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Check this article out for an MVC approach in Flutter: https://medium.com/@greg.perry/a-design-pattern-for-flutter-db6ccaea2413

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is correct. I used to create the following folders:

1. screens
2. utils
3. data
4. components
5. Models

And each component will have multiple folders inside, but I have to warn you about something.
**DO NOT MAKE EVERYTHING SPEREATED**
Some components you will use it once, don't make a file for one widget is used once!

Comment: thanks for share your advice but what about provider if this a good way if every screen have a own logic provider , i use provider for make screen listen to logic to rebuild

Answer (score 1):

Yes as many other programming languages , breaking the code into multiple files is a better choice , because you have more control on the things you do.
Although the common way among amateurs is to write all the code in a few files and then get missing in the code , it's better and professional to have multiple files.